# Mithril JS input checkbox events and element refresh

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

Working on a SPA with Mithril.js (love it!), but having a problem with input checkboxes not behaving correctly when I assign an "onchange" listener to them.

```
var Widget = {
  view: function(vnode) {
    return m("div", [ 
      m("input[type=checkbox]", {
        id: "cb" + vnode.attrs.id,
        checked: Boolean(vnode.attrs.state),
        onchange: function(e) {
          console.log(
            (e.target.checked) ? "ON" : "OFF"
          );
        }
      }),
      m("span", vnode.attrs.name)
    ]);
  }
}
```

The page will initially populate properly, with checkboxes in their correct state (on or off), but when clicking the checkbox... the checkbox element does not switch.

At first, I thought the onchange event was interrupting and blocking the DOM redraw. But, then found that if I removed the "checked: (true|false)" attribute the elements works as expected.
Of course, this is not acceptable. The checkbox state needs to be presented according to it's current on/off state in the database.

I'm unsure if this is weirdness with Mithrils DOM redraw. Or some other strange behavior with HTML checkboxes and Javascript in general.

Here is a sample illustrating the broken behavior.
https://jsfiddle.net/v1aq85kj/14/

Any ideas are appreciated!

- changed the "onchange" listener to an "onclick", but still the same.
- tried updating checkbox states with javascript after the page load, but seemed clunky and a bad way to address the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing out changing the value the checkbox binds to so checked/unchecked will never change.

something like this might help on the way

```
    onchange: function(e) {
      vnode.attrs.state = e.target.checked
    }
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you! Can't believe I missed something so simple. It makes sense now